# Creating stored procedure in Aginity Workbench (Error)

Tags: netezza

I am trying to create a stored procedure in [Aginity Workbench](https://www.aginity.com/workbench/) (v 4.7.0.2454), and as I click

```
"Object -> Stored Procedure -> Create Stored Procedure"
```

I get the error

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

I am not sure what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Known issue with Aginity 4.7, upgrading to 4.8 solved it.